# How to grep with specific format and get occurrences in Linux

Tags: linux, grep

I have logfiles and the lines are as follows,

```
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[75000000,074],passed
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2410,841,[750000,076],passed
2022-05-21 23:59:59,3002,892,[700000,78],passed
```

Are there any method to grep the `75` ,`70` as well? I have tried as below, but it is not working. I need the occurrences as well.

```
cat 20220521log|grep -E "2022-05-21 23|75" -C
```

Update:

Each and every log contains different timesamps and numbers as above mentioned. I need to check how many occurences can be found in each file according  to my pattern. Lets take 20220521 log file I need to check in how many line contains which starts the number field as `75`. All other fields are same as before.

```
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[75000000,074],passed //should take as one occurence
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[00000000,074],passed //should not consider
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[754324000,074],passed //should take as one occurence.
```

Comment: You need to be clearer about what exact patterns you want to match. Anything starting with `2022-05-21 23` that also has `[70` or `[75` later on the line: then `grep '^2022-05-21 23.*\[7[05]'`. What about 72? 76? Your `|` suggests "or" rather than "and": so anything with `2022-05-21 23` *or* `[70` or `[75`? Or what? What does "I need the occurrences as well" mean? Occurrences of what? Grep returns entire lines unless you use `-o`. What are you trying to do with `-C`? The `-C` option needs an argument.

Comment: @frabjous sorry for confusing. I have updated the question

Comment: use awk to summary for reporting

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to invoke several programs for that, perl (and probably also awk/python/...) can do it all:

```
perl -a -F'' -e 'BEGIN { print "status  count\n" } $a = join "",(@F[30,31]); next unless ($a == 70 or $a == 75); $b{$a}++; END { for (keys %b) { print "$_      $b{$_}\n" } }' < 705361.log
```

(`705361` is the id of the question, just a convention I use when creating files/directories to test commands before putting them here)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get all the occurrences as well as the count, you could simply do something like:

```
grep '^2022-05-21.*\[75' logfilename | tee >(wc -l)
```

This will print all lines starting with `2022-05-21` and has `[75` later on the line. (I assume each line only has one number field starting in brackets.) Then on the last line of output it will print the count (by having tee send a duplication of the output to be counted by wc).

If each day has its own file already, you can leave out `^2022-05-21.*`; if you only need the count and not the lines, you can remove `| tee >(wc -l)` and just use `grep -c` (lowercase c).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like:

```
<your-file grep -Po '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d(?=:\d\d:\d\d,\d+,\d+,\[75)' |
  uniq -c
```

For a count of lines whose fourth field starts with `[75` per hour (assuming the lines are in chronological order).

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -v i=1 '/^2022-05-21[^[]*\[(75|70)/{$(NF+1)=i++; print}' input_file
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[75000000,074],passed //should take as one occurence 1
2022-05-21 23:59:59,2406,842,[754324000,074],passed //should take as one occurence. 2
```

Answer (score -1):

code:

```
cat 20220521log | (echo "status count" ; awk -F "," '{list[substr($4,2,2)]++} END {for(i in list){print i, list[i]}}') | column -nt
```

result :

[image: result]

Comment: 1) please do not post image, just simply copy/paste and format result. 2) did you test your actual command  (e.g. piping to `echo` ) ?